# How do you handle lack of acknowledgement /appreciation of efforts?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes

What can you do in a case where ,you put in a lot of effort to solve someone's problem (and maybe even solve it) but then recieve no upvotes from the person ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always hope it serves the good of the greater community, and future visitors with the same problem may upvote it. It can be frustrating in the short term, but satisfying when you realize questions you've answered get a steady amount of attention, and upvotes slowly trickle in from a certain percentage of those visitors.

If it's an ultra-specific answer to a very specific question that others are unlikely to find useful in the future, then.. yeah, not much. You could leave a constructive comment, asking whether they've solved their issue or need more help. That may draw them back in, and they'll consider your answer again, or mark it if they found it useful but got distracted by the next shiny thing.

In the case where an asker is brand new and has never accepted an answer (and *only* in this case, indicating they may not know how the site works), I've even left a reminder that marking the most helpful answer helps future visitors, with a link to the [relevant documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Be careful not to badger though.

Comment: Your suggestion about leaving a reminder for new askers make sense.

Answer (score 6):

At the end of the day, you have to decide for yourself if you're getting enough in return for your efforts. And what kind of return is meaningful to you is very personal. There are a lot of possibilities:

- Internet points.
- Direct acknowledgement by upvotes and comments.
- Enjoyment from solving interesting problems.
- What you learn from researching topics in the process of answering questions.
- Pride from providing high level content, even if you don't get direct and immediate recognition.
- Getting your name out in the public, hoping to improve e.g. your professional recognition.
- Satisfaction from giving back to a community that you have also profited from.

If you only care about the first of these two, you probably need to focus on popular topics, and questions that can be answered quickly. If you have other aspects that motivate you, like some of the remaining items on my list above, you can be happy answering questions even without always getting lots of votes for them.

Yes, it can at times be slightly frustrating if you spend 1 or 2 hours on an answer that might be fairly detailed, or required significant research, and you don't get a single upvote. The way I deal with that is that I look at the total of my answers. You may sometimes not get the votes you "deserve", but other times get a handful of upvotes for an answer that was really trivial. In total, it tends to balance itself out. And even if the votes say otherwise, the answers that I believe have technical substance are much more meaningful to me.

Comment: I agree that it balances out, especially over time.